# get a variable's content, from the contents of another variable, both variable names have the same trailing number

Tags: linux, bash, variables

in a bash script, How do I get a variable's content, from the contents of another variable, both variable names have the same trailing number?

```
IP1=192.168.0.17
DIR1=/mnt/2tb/archive/src/
IP2=192.168.0.11
DIR2=~/src/
IP3=192.168.0.113
DIR3=~/src/

#get local ip and set variable HOST to local ip
HOST=$(ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')

# get HOST source DIR as variable from ip and preset variables

echo $HOSTDIR
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval like below:

```
HOSTDIR=$(for i in {1..3}; do eval if [[ \$IP$i == "$HOST" ]] \; then echo \$DIR$i \; fi; done)
```

But using associative arrays as suggested in another solution is a better idea.

Comment: thank you, that is exactly the one liner I was looking for :D

Answer (score 0):

if there are just 3, use an if statement

```
if [ $HOST = $IP1 ]; then
    HOSTDIR=$DIR1
elif [ $HOST = $IP2 ]; then
    HOSTDIR=$DIR2
...
```

Another approach is to use indirect expansion:

```
for num in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
do
    ip=IP$num
    MYIP=${!ip}
    if [ $HOST = $MYIP ]; then
        dir=DIR$num
        HOSTDIR=${!dir}
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: I want to be able to add more in the future, or have different dirs for each machine(ip) I would like it to be relative to that trailing number :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with an associative array.

Here's an example of how they are used:

```
#! /bin/bash

typeset -A dirs           # -A for associative array, -a for indexed arrays

dirs["192.168.0.17"]=foo  # build your map of ip -> dirs
dirs["192.168.0.18"]=bar

ip=192.168.0.17
echo ${dirs[$ip]}         # print the value associated with $ip
ip=192.168.0.18
echo ${dirs[$ip]}
```